# Ionic 2, how to properly use alert

Tags: ionic2

I am programming using Ionic 2, and I want to show a pop-up alert when a button is clicked.

This is the code in my *home.html*:

```
<button (click)='openFilters()'>CLICK</button>
```

And in my *home.ts*

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Page, NavController, Alert} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(nav: NavController, alertCtrl: AlertController) {

  }

  openFilters() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Low battery',
        subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
        buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

I have read some StackOverflow questions on this topic and tried to implement it like this:

```
openFilters() {
    let alert:Alert = Alert.create({
        title: 'Low battery',
        subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
        buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    this.nav.present(alert);
  }
```

Still, I accomplished nothing; I get errors.

Comment: Which version of Ionic are you using in your project? You can check that by executing `ionic info` in your project folder, and would be the one that says `Ionic Framework Version`. The reason I'm asking this, is because the way `Alerts` are created changed from version `beta.10` to `beta.11`.

Comment: You should probably show what errors you get

Comment: My ionic info:

Cordove CLI: 6.3.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.37
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v4.4.7

Comment: The errors I get: Cannot find name 'AlertController'. and Property alertCtrl does not exits on type 'HomePage'

Comment: I have reworded your introduction a little bit, to improve the english. On Stack Overflow, everybody is encouraged to edit and re-edit questions to make them as good as possible; for this question, I think it would be improved further if you could show and describe the errors you say you are getting?

Answer (score 11):

Make sure to import this:

```
import {AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
```

and have code such as this:

```
constructor(private alertController: AlertController) {

}


openFilters() {
    let alert = this.alertController.create({
        title: 'Example',
        subTitle: 'Example subtitle',
        buttons: ['OK']
    });

    alert.present();
}
```

Things have changed with Beta 11, and it seems as if the documentation online is not yet updated, you can always go into the ionic-angular folder in your node_modules and find the component that you are trying to use for examples of better documentation.

Comment: Ok it works, the only difference is I have to add private. Why is that?

Comment: Does it mean, all constructor that I'm going to use has to be private?

Comment: you can add private or public but in your question you didn't add any. By adding private or public a local variable is then automatically added to the class which means you can then call `this.alertController`

Comment: When I first install ionic 2, in the constructor there is allreadey nav:NavController, and it didn;t have any public or private attribute. Are there any difference?

Comment: It appears that you were importing Alert and not AlertController too.